# Xcode quit unexpectedly

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode4, osx-snow-leopard

After update my MacBook to Snow Leopard I installed a new xcode 4 but he didn't opened: `"Xcode quit unexpectedly"`.

Xcode encountered an internal logic error. Choose "**Continue**" to continue running Xcode in an inconsistent state.  Choose "**Crash**" to halt Xcode and file a bug with Crash Reporter. Choosing "**Crash**" will result in the loss of all unsaved data.

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Couldn't load plug-in 'com.apple.dt.gpu.GPURenderTargetEditor' while firing fault for extension 'Xcode.IDEKit.EditorDocument.GPUTrace'
UserInfo: {
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 UserInfo=0x2009f9180 \"Loading a plug-in failed.\" Underlying Error=(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 UserInfo=0x2009fb080 \"The bundle \U201cGPUDebuggerFoundation\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.\" (dlopen_preflight(/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/GPUDebuggerFoundation.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/GPUDebuggerFoundation): Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice\n  Referenced from: /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUTools.framework/Versions/A/GPUTools\n  Reason: image not found))";
}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff89d2f766 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff865c1f03 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x000000010001bdf0 -[DVTExtension _fireExtensionFault] (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000100006096 __38-[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff88454fbb dispatch_barrier_sync_f (in libSystem.B.dylib)
  5  0x000000010000603f -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
  6  0x000000010001bb8b -[DVTExtension _valueForKey:inParameterData:usingSchema:] (in DVTFoundation)
  7  0x000000010001bacf -[DVTExtension valueForKey:] (in DVTFoundation)
  8  0x0000000100a0f711 +[IDEEditorDocument _validateDocumentExtension:] (in IDEKit)
  9  0x0000000100946b06 __60+[IDEDocumentController _THREAD_allEditorDocumentExtensions]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEKit)
 10  0x00007fff88438705 dispatch_once_f (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 11  0x0000000100946893 +[IDEDocumentController _THREAD_allEditorDocumentExtensions] (in IDEKit)
 12  0x0000000100b0650d -[IDEDocumentController documentClassNames] (in IDEKit)
 13  0x00007fff8045fbee -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _installOpenRecentMenus] (in AppKit)
 14  0x00007fff80428dd9 -[NSApplication finishLaunching] (in AppKit)
 15  0x00007fff80428554 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 16  0x00007fff804213b0 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 17  0x0000000100000eec
 18  0x0000000000000002
```

What I need to do?

Comment: You better stay on Xcode 3.2 if you remain on Snow Leopard. I've seen these kind of bugs happening with no longer supported sdk/libraries.

Are you just opening XCode, or you're opening a .xcodeproj file from 3.2 project ???

Comment: Xcode 4 officially supports Snow Leopard. This is a *bug*, so report it to Apple at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Now all works good. I removed all old data xcode 3 and reinstall xcode 4.

Answer (score 1):

I see this often, just click on "continue" and as soon as you get to a stopping point consider  quitting and re-launching Xcode. In short Xcode is has bugs.

Comment: "Continue" didn't help... Cxode didn't opeded. :(

Comment: Well, continue is just a chance thing. So, the other thing to to uninstall Xcode, there is a script to you can use to be through and re-install. Good luck!